# Printing on museum quality glass

Tags: printing

I'm looking for a service bureau that prints on museum quality glass. Does anyone know of a printer who provides this service?

Comment: Why do you need museum quality glass to print upon? The two most important qualities of museum quality glass are preventing harmful UV rays from getting through the glass to whatever is displayed behind the glass and preventing reflections of the ambient light in the room from obscuring what is behind the glass. Since printing on glass usually involves printing on the front side of the glass, neither of these concerns would apply.

Comment: Also see: [What method is used for printing onto museum-quality glass?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69289/what-method-is-used-for-printing-onto-museum-quality-glass)

Comment: Limbic System Photoworks, maybe is wise to mention continent, country, county (if applicable).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [Fracture](https://www.fractureme.com/).

> Instead of printing on paper, we print directly on glass. Instead of separating the picture, frame, and mount, a Fracture combines all three into a beautiful, lasting, final product.

If you can make due with acrylic you will find many more options such as:

- [Bayphoto](https://www.bayphoto.com/wall-displays/acrylic/acrylic-prints/)
- [Whitewall](https://us.whitewall.com/photo-lab/acrylic-glass/photo-print-under-acrylic-glass)